# Logic Apps - Extract individual values from Azure Function where Results Delivered as an Array

Tags: arrays, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

My Azure function is returning this result:

[
"MC MzdmvECSfdAbuxk0hrfYufPvdsCKQz_fYxiGRAw9wA7Odl7knmYRv9EfkLIkGBMTMC7vthNv70wKky1qvN8mTMdMWYXuuhAa-RpJEg489biX0Y8qcKD5Ju4mqXXcCdCAUOnJsEyug1_QzYuiu2gBIueXu4Mj7aRo2UcJqSsjssY:o8tqQZK4zHh+NB9lTfN59Je6UfU=",
"Mon, 17 Apr 2023 13:48:09 GMT",
"357f6d2b-61fc-4943-9451-a8dd577bfb71"
]

This is achieved using this code in my AzureFunction:

```
const everything = JSON.stringify(([myString, date, reqId]));

context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: everything
};
```

In Logic Apps, how can I extract the three values into distinct variables? Once it arrives in LA, it does not seem to function like an array any more.

Any info you have would be very much appreciated.
Many thanks

[image: Logic Apps Azure Function setup]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could get the desired results following the below process.

Here is the code in my Azure functions where I have used the same values as yours.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string[] Array = new string[3]{"MC MzdmvECSfdAbuxk0hrfYufPvdsCKQz_fYxiGRAw9wA7Odl7knmYRv9EfkLIkGBMTMC7vthNv70wKky1qvN8mTMdMWYXuuhAa-RpJEg489biX0Y8qcKD5Ju4mqXXcCdCAUOnJsEyug1_QzYuiu2gBIueXu4Mj7aRo2UcJqSsjssY:o8tqQZK4zHh+NB9lTfN59Je6UfU=","Mon, 17 Apr 2023 13:48:09 GMT","357f6d2b-61fc-4943-9451-a8dd577bfb71"};
    var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Array);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

*Results:*

[image]

Below is the logic app flow that worked for me.

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

Below is the code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HttpTrigger1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {},
                    "function": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/abc/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<FUNCTION_NAME>/functions/HttpTrigger1"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Function"
            },
            "var1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var1",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{body('HttpTrigger1')[0]}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HttpTrigger1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "var2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{body('HttpTrigger1')[1]}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HttpTrigger1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "var3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var3",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{body('HttpTrigger1')[2]}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HttpTrigger1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this, I really think this could work. Could you possible share your variable 'code view' tab please as I get the error shown below:

My variable code looks like this @{body('Run_API_PreScript')[0]}

InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'var_myAuth' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'body('Run_API_PreScript')[0]' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Comment: thank you for adding your code, my variables definitely look the same as yours, so there is another problem. The only difference I can see is your Azure Function component does not insist upon a Method - do you know why this is? I've added screenshot of mine for comparison.

Comment: @KodeNode, I have created function in my function app before only instead of directly creating while adding steps in logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using Azure substring functions to extract the required values.

Example:

```
Value 1 = @{substring(body('Run_API_PreScript'), add(2,0),sub(indexOf(body('Run_API_PreScript'), ','),3))}

Value 2 = @{substring(body('Run_API_PreScript'), 208,29)}

Value 3 = @{substring(body('Run_API_PreScript'), 240,36)
```

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)